# probability question on characteristic function

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I got a big problem with my exam practice question on characteristic function. Here are two.

> Let $X$, $Y$ be two independent random variables with the following characteristic functions:    $$\Phi_X(\theta)=\tfrac{1}{4}e^{i\theta}  + \tfrac{3}{4}e^{2i\theta} , \quad \Phi_Y(\theta)=\exp(e^{i\theta}-1). $$
>
> (a) Find $E[X^2]$.
>   (b) Find $P(X+Y)=2$.
>   (c) Does $X+Y$ admit a Lebesgue density?
>
> ---
>
> Defined on some common probability space,
>   two random variables $X$, $Y$ have the
>   following joint characteristic function:
>   $$\Phi_{X,Y}(\theta,\eta) = \frac{1}{1+\theta^2} \cdot \exp(-i\eta-\eta^2)$$
>
> (a) Find $\Phi_X(\theta)$ and $E[X]$ and $E[X^2]$.
>
> (b) Find $\Phi_{X+Y}(\theta)$ and $\operatorname{Var}(X+Y)$.
>
> (c) Prove or disprove that $X+Y$ is absolutely continuous.

Unfortunately, the lecture notes are quite poor. I am wondering if anyone can give me a link of some good notes on this part (characteristic function and convolution). Thanks and regards.

Comment: Please see [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/464/264) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/161783) for how to format your mathematics expressions with LaTeX, and see [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for how to use Markdown formatting. If you need to format more advanced math, there are many excellent LaTeX references on the internet, including StackExchange's own [TeX.SE](http://tex.stackexchange.com/) site. If you see a piece of LaTeX you want to know the code for on the site, you can right click on it, go to "Show Math As", then choose "TeX Commands".

Comment: For the first question, use the fact that you can differentiate the characteristic function. I guess in question b there is a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few hints.

**Hint 1:** Since the characteristic function
$$
\Phi_X(\theta)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{it\theta}\phi(t)\,\mathrm{d}t
$$
If we take the first derivative with respect to $\theta$ and evaluate at $0$, we get
$$
-i\Phi_X^{\prime}(0)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty t\phi(t)\,\mathrm{d}t=\mathrm{E}[X]
$$
If we take the second derivative with respect to $\theta$ and evaluate at $0$, we get
$$
-\Phi_X^{\prime\prime}(0)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty t^2\phi(t)\,\mathrm{d}t=\mathrm{E}[X^2]
$$

**Hint 2:** the characteristic function of the sum of two random variables is the product of their characteristic functions.

**Hint 3:** The [Riemann-Lebesgue Lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Lebesgue_lemma)