# How to use joint characteristic function to calculate characteristic function for single variables?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, fourier-analysis

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [probability question on characteristic function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/155849/probability-question-on-characteristic-function)

It is a problem in my practice exam.

Defined on some common probability space,
two random variables $X$, $Y$ have the
following joint characteristic function:
$$\Phi_{X,Y}(\theta,\eta) = \frac{1}{1+\theta^2} \cdot \exp(-i\eta-\eta^2)$$

> (a) Find $\Phi_X(\theta)$ and $E[X]$ and $E[X^2]$.
>
> (b) Find $\Phi_{X+Y}(\theta)$ and $\operatorname{Var}(X+Y)$.
>
> (c) Prove or disprove that $X+Y$ is absolutely continuous.

Is there any way to calculate  $\Phi_X(\theta)$ and  $\Phi_Y(\theta)$ from the given joint characteristic function? I think the remaining parts will be easy once I get these two.
Thanks and regards.

Comment: The characteristic function is defined to be $E e^{\theta iX + \eta iY}$. What happens when (say) $\eta=0$?

Answer (score 3):

$$
\Phi_{X}(\theta)=\Phi_{X,Y}(\theta,0)\qquad
\Phi_{Y}(\theta)=\Phi_{X,Y}(0,\theta)\qquad
\Phi_{X+Y}(\theta)=\Phi_{X,Y}(\theta,\theta)
$$