# Proof uncorrelatedness and zero mean RVs from joint characteristic function

Tags: probability

How to prove that, X and Y RVs are zero mean and uncorrelated using the below joint characteristic function?
$$Φ_{XY}(u,v) = e^{(-2u^2 - 8v^2)}$$

The question is such like that, but i guess there is mistake and right part of the equation should be in the E{} (Expected Value of).

I know that if X and Y are uncorrelated, E{XY} = E{X}.E{Y}. If they are both zero mean, E{XY}=0. Thus they will be orthogonal, but didn't get any clue about how to solve.
[This link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/155849/probability-question-on-characteristic-function) is a little helpful but not shows how to calculate E{X} in the second question.

Comment: You should be able to realize on the spot that the function on the RHS implies that X and Y are actually independent.

Answer (score 2):

Let's address both parts of that question:

Independence:

Let $\tilde{X}$ be a RV that has characteristic function e^{-2u^2} (Does such an $\tilde{X}$ exist? Why?), $\tilde{Y}$ be a RV that has characteristic function e^{-8v^2}, and let $\tilde{X}$ and $\tilde{Y}$ be independent. What is the characteristic function of $\tilde{X}$$\tilde{Y}$? What can we say about the distribution of two random variables that have identical characteristic functions?

Now, independence implies uncorrelated-ness so you would be done.

Zero-mean:

Characteristic function is \phi(u) = $\mathbb{E}[e^{iuX}]. What happens if you take the derivative of this expression with respect to u and set u = 0?